# "Failed to decode downloaded font" error but font is working Angular 5

Tags: angular, webpack, fonts

In my Angular 5 app I have the lato-font downloaded in my node_modules folder, and it is displaying correctly when deployed to a server.  However I have the "Failed to decode downloaded font:   OTS parsing error: invalid version tag" warnings still displaying.

I have been using my setup for a while with no problems, this only started recently.  My Angular app is being built in prod mode and packaged with Webpack.  I suppose my main confusion is why I am getting these warnings and yet the lato-font is working fine.  I'm asking here as I can't find another question that has my specific issue.

In my package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "ag-grid": "^16.0.1",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^16.0.0",
    "angular-font-awesome": "3.1.2",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lato-font": "^3.0.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
  }
```

In my angular-cli.json:

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
    "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-material.css",
    "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
    "../node_modules/lato-font/css/lato-font.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
```

Edit:  I've managed to get past this issue as explained in my comment below.  I'm still curious why I was getting warnings in the browser console after I downloaded the font using NPM, had it packaged with Webpack and it was correctly displaying.

Comment: You have the "Failed to decode downloaded font: OTS parsing error: invalid version tag" warnings still displaying _where_? The server doesn't do anything with the font, it's not rendering any content, so what's _actually_ loading the font?

Comment: It was displaying in the browser console (Chrome).  The font was being packaged with my application by Webpack and the font files were being served along side the other files of the Angular app.  I've managed to get around the issue by linking to the Google font directly in my index.html using a <link>, rather than downloading using npm and packaging it with my application.

Comment: given that that's the official distribution, that's a sensible thing to do. However, the OTS warning really does mean "this font has instructions in it, or is missing data, that is necessary for it to work as webfont", so either whoever created the npm package did a bad job of it, or Chrome tightened its font sanitizing (always possible, webfonts can be a vector for exploits).